# Does javascript's promise not catch inside another promise?

Tags: javascript

Using promises I have to have double of the "catch" as it seems not to catch it's childs promises?

```
Facility.userHaveAccess(locationObject.created_by, locationObject.facility_id)
.then(() => {
  Locations.create(locationObject)
  .then( (result: any) => {
    res.send(result)
  })
  .catch(err => { return res.status(err.status).send({ error: err.message }) })
})
.catch(err => { return res.status(err.status).send({ error: err.message }) })
```

I was hoping to not need double of the errors as they are mostly exactly the same?

Removing the first .catch throws this:

```
(node:3108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
(node:3108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3108) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: You should return the promise created by  `Locations.create()`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer "Location.create(xxx)" is returning "new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...". My question was if I remove the first ".catch" i get that error. I thought the "outer catch" was supposed to handle all "errors" inside and get the reject from Location.create?

Comment: But you're not returning that promise from the `then()` callback. You need something like `return Location.create()` or better yet, flatten out the `then`s.

Comment: Could you elaborate about what flatten out is? :)

Comment: Sure — probably easier in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return promises from the `then()` functions. This is how the next part of the chain knows when the async action is over. It's pretty natural to do this if you flatten the structure out an use the implicit return of arrow functions. Doing this, your function will look more like:

```
Facility.userHaveAccess(locationObject.created_by, locationObject.facility_id)
.then(() => Locations.create(locationObject))
.then((result: any) => res.send(result))
.catch(err => res.status(err.status).send({ error: err.message }))
```

And errors will filter to the last `catch()`

Comment: Thank you, will mark as answer but have to wait 4 minutes.